# String decoding of format \x123 in Python

Tags: python, string, decode, encode

Do anybody know that type of string?
And how to convert it to readable format in Python?
This data from log file of the mobile app (it might be in Russian)

```
"title":"\x{41E}\x{442}\x{441}\x{440}\x{43E}\x{447}\x{43A}\x{430} \x{43F}\x{43E} \x{43A}\x{440}\x{435}\x{434}\x{438}\x{442}\x{443}"
```

Thanks ahead!

Comment: from where you are reading this string?

Comment: @komatiraju032 it's data from log file of the mobile app (it might be in Russian)

Comment: `bytes(title.replace('x{', 'u0').replace('}', ''), 'raw-unicode-escape').decode('unicode-escape')` => `'Отсрочка по кредиту'`. Which google translates as "Credit deferral".

Answer (score 1):

For me it does look like hex-codes of characters, I would extract codes, treat them as base-16 integers and convert to characters. That is

```
title = r"\x{41E}\x{442}\x{441}\x{440}\x{43E}\x{447}\x{43A}\x{430} \x{43F}\x{43E} \x{43A}\x{440}\x{435}\x{434}\x{438}\x{442}\x{443}"
codes = [code.strip('{} ') for code in title.split(r"\x") if code]
characters = [chr(int(code, 16)) for code in codes]
output = ''.join(characters)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
Отсрочкапокредиту
```

Comment: You skipped spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

data = r'"\x{41E}\x{442}\x{441}\x{440}\x{43E}\x{447}\x{43A}\x{430} \x{43F}\x{43E} \x{43A}\x{440}\x{435}\x{434}\x{438}\x{442}\x{443} "'

print(json.loads(data.replace('{','').replace('}','').replace('x', 'u0')))
```

…and the output is `Отсрочка по кредиту`.